# Checking Dictionary Key Existence in Golang on right side of boolean condition

Tags: go, conditional-statements, short-circuiting

I have an array of maps in golang, I'm iterating over the list and need to check if a key from the current iteration exists in the next map in the list, I know the normal way to check if an element exists in a map is to do:

```golang
if _, ok := m[key]; ok {
  ...
}
```

but is there a way to do this?

```golang
if index < len(arr)-1 && (_, ok := arr[index+1][key]; ok) {
  ...
}
```

where short-circuiting would work and the code remains in one line?

Comment: If a key does not exist in a map it would return the zero value, e.g. if you map would look like this `map[string]string` it would return an empty string. Then your `if` condition could look like this: `if index < len(arr)-1 && arr[index+1][key] != "" {`

Comment: @StephanSchlecht Please note that the map could contain items which hold "" as value. So `map[key] == ""` does not mean that the key does not exist.

Comment: Yes sure, if the zero value is in the range of expected valid data values for the use case of the OP, it cannot be used as sentinel in this case.

Comment: The map contains set of structs, the zero-value could be present so I cannot check for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way to do it in one line.

Hey, [Go even does not have the `?:` operator](https://go.dev/doc/faq#Does_Go_have_a_ternary_form):

> The reason ?: is absent from Go is that the language's designers had seen the operation used too often to create impenetrably complex expressions. The if-else form, although longer, is unquestionably clearer. A language needs only one conditional control flow construct.

And one of [Go's proverbs](https://go-proverbs.github.io/) is **Clear is better than clever**.

So don't struggle with it. Just write it like this:

```golang
if index < len(arr)-1 {
    if _, ok := arr[index+1][key]; ok {
        //...
    }
}
```

Regarding you're iterating over the list, maybe it's better to write it like this:

```golang
// assumes arr has at least 1 items
for index := range arr[0 : len(arr)-1] {
    if _, ok := arr[index+1][key]; ok {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I was afraid of this, but I agree, I don't think this is worth struggling over. I was just curious if some workaround exists. I'm still new to Golang so I don't know all of the intricacies of the language quite yet